# Mysql ascii procedure

Tags: mysql, ascii

I have some bad strings in my MySQL tables.

I'd like to delete all strings with ASCII character greater than `127`. Is there any MySQL function to understand if my string contains bad (greater than `127`)  values?

Thanks,

Paolo

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column charset is latin1, the table is called test.t1 and the column with bad characters is called s, the following brute force solution works (tested):

```
perl -e '$expr="s";for $i  (128..255) { $expr = "replace($expr,char($i),'"''"')";} print "update test.t1 set s=$expr"' | mysql
```

You may need to supply the authentication credentials to mysql command line client.